# GitKraken interoperability with git-crypt

Tags: git, gitkraken, git-crypt

[git-crypt](https://github.com/AGWA/git-crypt) works wonderfully when using git CLI.  I have set everything up appropriately for git-crypt (`.gitattributes`).  After creating/editing a file I want encrypted I perform:

```
git add .
```

The files have been staged and now I perform:

```
git commit -m "Commit encrypted file"
git push
```

But when I use GitKraken and stage a file it does not seem to duplicate the `git add .` CLI.

Has anyone successfully used GitKraken and git-crypt?

Comment: Similar post - https://www.reddit.com/r/git/comments/admsh1/gitkraken_not_using_gitattributes_filters/

Answer (score 0):

Gitkraken doesn't support git-cyrpt yet (doesn't use the .gitattributes file)
Gitkraken has an existing feature request to add support for git-crypt that's currently under review.
Perhaps also write to gitkraken to get a "+1" vote on the feature request.

Comment: I see this: https://feedback.gitkraken.com/suggestions/211286/gitcrypt-support but that's months after your comment. Where can we see this feature request?

Comment: the response from gitkraken support was "We do not have any public facing feature requests at this time, it is all internal. I can note additional users interest as well, let me know. I also know that our team is considering this possibility of public feature requests in the future." (5th march 2021)